# Get element of table by instance of foreign key.

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in Django:

```
class Blog(models.Model):

   author = ForeignKey(Author)
   post = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I need to get the Blog entry by instance of Author:

```
author_one = Author (name ='John')
author_one.save()
blog_entry = Blog.objects.get(author = author_one)
```

Do I need to add related name to Author Foreignkey field to get results? What is the correct way get row of a table by foreign key field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify a thing, using **get()** in this situation isn't right, quoting **get()** docs :

> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the **get()** method on a Manager which returns the object directly

Alternatively with what [Wtower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940098/wtower) mentioned,you can also use:

```
blog_entry = Blog.objects.filter(author=author_one)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Please check the get query,
>
> change this from

```
blog_entry = Blog.objects.get(author = author_one)
```

> to

```
blog_entry = Blog.objects.get(author=author_one)
```

> Because "=" doesn't take spaces when extracting object.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the related data as:

```
author_one.blog_set
```

Reference: [Django docs: Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/)

There is no need to specify a `related_name`, but if you do, then you can use it similarly, eg:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
   author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='author_blogs')
...
author_one_blogs = author_one.author_blogs.all()
```

Reference: Django docs: [Foreign key related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), [Following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)